# Removing rows between earlier removed rows in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row, subtotal

I am to write VBA code that would remove certain rows (with certain words in a column). I have one that is below. I have problem with removing also all rows that are between two earlier removed rows (which are subtotals)(*and as condition that this is only one row between them, if more not to delete them)

Could you please advise is there a way to overcome this problem?
Please let me know if this question is vague (as I am newcomer)

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim SrchStr As String

Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("F1", ActiveSheet.Range("F10000").End(xlUp))
SrchStr = InputBox("Please Enter A Search String")
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find(SrchStr, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Suggested to add commas on your question as it is very difficult to read, let alone understanding the question.

Comment: If I enter "XYZ", the existing code will remove every row that contains "XYZ" in column F.  But your question does not seem to be related to this code. Sometime earlier you deleted two rows. Let us call those rows N amd M. Rows below N and M will have moved up to fill the gap. You now either want rows between N and M deleted or they are being deleted and you don't want them deleted. How would a macro know the values of N amd M? I assume the rows between N amd M will have moved because of the new deletions. How would a macro know the new positions of the rows between the original N and M?

Comment: thanks, good point. I was just wondering if there is a way to detect, before deleting rows, which rows are to be deleted and adding also removal of rows when there is only one row directly between two of them (as there are subtotals), not after the deletion

Comment: but i find it complicated now so I think I ll have to do this only with autofilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the column of interest (F in this case) and you're also prompting the user to specify the string for deletion, which sounds like the perfect recipe for crafty use of the `Range.Autofilter` method. (Here's an MSDN link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofilter(VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofilter%28VS.80%29.aspx))

Supposing the block of data you are operating on goes from A:F, you could write:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteRowsWithAutoFilter()

Dim DataRng As Range, DeleteMe As Range
Dim SrchStr As String

'set references up-front
Set DataRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("F10000").End(xlUp))
SrchStr = InputBox("Please Enter A Search String")

'turn off alerts for delete action
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
DataRng.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=SrchStr '<~ apply autofilter
With DataRng
    Set DeleteMe = .Offset(1, 0) '<~ set the delete range
    DeleteMe.Delete
End With
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,  this one deleted all the rows, I dont know why :). Thanks

Comment: That was your goal, right? The loop in your code above iterates through `SrchRng`, deleting rows that have a match in column F. My script simply deletes all rows that match the user-inputted string by using `.AutoFilter`

Comment: Yes, after I input any word the macro removes every row except first and last one (and sometimes one in the middle), only with reamining InputBox empty it removes only empty rows. I am a beginner and I do it by trial and error with the use of the internet and VBA basics, I could not understand many things yet :). Its a pity that I can t post an example. Thanks